# Turn 1 row into 2 rows, using 1 col value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running this query (sort of)

```
SELECT
        [RecordID]
    ,   [PermitType]
    ,   [Additional Permits]
    ,   [License_1]
    ,   [License_2]                 
    FROM Permits 
    WHERE
        [Permit Type] = 'Additional or Replacement'
        [RecordID] = 'P2023-10669'
```

it returns this result back

```
RecordID    PermitType  Additional Permits  License_1   License_2
P2023-10669 Replacement 2                   Rh3184      Aez8532
```

al though the expected output should be...

```
RecordID    PermitType  Additional Permits  License_1   License_2
P2023-10669 Replacement 2                   Rh3184      
P2023-10669 Replacement 2                               Aez8532
```

I would like to learn how to turn this single row, into two. By the number of additional permits (2), I should be able to read 2 rows, and so on.

How can this be done? I tried to follow tutorials on pivot/unpivot values, but I have only ran into failure.

Comment: Seems like you should `JOIN` to a numbers table/tally.

Comment: Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. show us some sample table data and also the expected result.

Comment: `SELECT
    ,` is a syntax error

Comment: In SQL Server 2022 and forward you can call a GENERATE_SERIES-function that generates a rang of values between from and to. For older versions, you can use either Tally tables, CTEs, pseudo cross join or whatever else that tickles your fancy.

Comment: Can `Additional Permits` have a value grater than 2? If so, what are your expected results? What is the highest value for `Additional Permits`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `CROSS APPLY (VALUES`

```sql
SELECT
        p.RecordID
    ,   p.PermitType
    ,   p.[Additional Permits]
    ,   v.License_1
    ,   v.License_2                 
FROM Permits p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
       (v.License_1, NULL)
    ,  (NULL, v.License_2)
) v(License_1, License_2)
WHERE
    p.[Permit Type] = 'Additional or Replacement' AND
    p.RecordID = 'P2023-10669' AND
    (v.License_1 IS NOT NULL OR v.License_2 IS NOT NULL);
```

Do yourself a favour and don't use columns that needing quoting with `[]`.

Comment: I suppose we should hope the OP doesn't have a value like `15` for `Additional Permits`, and it's always `2`.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense, because there are only two columns.

Comment: My point is that then the OP will want *15* columns. Unfortunately the OP has given *one* example.